# How to add proper error handling to cats-effect's Resource

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

I am trying to get some basic file IO (write/read) in a purely functional way using [cats-effect](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/). After following [this](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/tutorial/tutorial.html) tutorial, here is what I ended up with for reading a file:

```scala
private def readFile(): IO[String] = for {
  lines <-  bufferedReader(new File(filePath)).use(readAllLines)
} yield lines.mkString

def bufferedReader(f: File): Resource[IO, BufferedReader] =
  Resource.make {
    IO(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)))
  } { fileReader =>
    IO(fileReader.close()).handleErrorWith(_ => IO.unit)
  }
```

Now in the `handleErrorWith` function I could log any error occuring, but how can I  add proper error handling to this (e.g. return a `Resource[IO, Either[CouldNotReadFileError, BufferedReader]]`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proper error handling can be added via the use of `.attempt` on the returned IO value:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val resourceOrError: IO[Either[Throwable, String]] = bufferedReader(new File(""))
  .use(resource => IO(resource.lines().iterator().asScala.mkString))
  .attempt
```

If you want to lift that into your own ADT, you can use `leftMap`:

```
import cats.syntax.either._

final case class CouldNotReadError(e: Throwable)

val resourceOrError: IO[Either[CouldNotReadError, String]] =
  bufferedReader(new File(""))
    .use(resource => IO(resource.lines().iterator().asScala.mkString))
    .attempt
    .map(_.leftMap(CouldNotReadError))
```

Additionally, you might be interested in the [ZIO](https://scalaz.github.io/scalaz-zio/datatypes/io.html) datatype, which has [supported cats-effect instances](https://scalaz.github.io/scalaz-zio/interop/catseffect.html), and has a slightly different shape of the form `IO[E, A]` where `E` captures the error effect type.